# Firebase Firestore databse along with Google Cloud IAM & admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

## Documentation

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#go) mentions:

> To use the Firebase Admin SDK on your own server, use a service account.

> Go to IAM & admin > Service accounts in the Google Cloud console. Generate a new private key and save the JSON file. Then use the file to initialize the SDK:

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

## Problem

I went to [IAM & admin > Service accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) and it was empty. Then I created a new project, but there was no way to connect it to my Firebase project. I'm just confused about how to connect my Firebase project to the Google Cloud project and its *IAM & admin* section.

Basically, I cannot figure out any connection between these two:

- https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/...
- https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=...

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked on `Manage Resources` on the left menu. Then I could see the Firebase project.

[image: Screenshot]

The Firebase project details are shown like this:

[image: Screenshot details]

## Not there yet

But I still don't know how to do the documentation instructions:

> Generate a new private key and save the JSON file.

## Almost there

I figured that I just had to simply click on the `Service Accounts` on the left menu:

[image: Screenshot: menu]

## Done

By clicking on the three-dots icon of `Actions`, and then by clicking on `Manage Keys`, I finally created the required JSON File.

[image: Screenshot: actions: manage keys]